# ItemsControl and controls attached properties

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I'm trying to implement a diagram with movable/resizeable parts in WPF.
I would like to use ItemsControl with ItemsPanel configured to be "DynamicCanvas".
All you need to know about DynamicCanvas right now is that it acts like a usual canvas - with one exception - it utilizes attached properties to store information about X,Y attributes on its children.

My code:

```
<ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1,Path=SelectedItem.Source.Table}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <s:TableControl Table="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>

        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!--<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">-->
            <c:DynamicCanvas SizeHeightToContent="True" SizeWidthToContent="True"  ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" PreviewMouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" IsHitTestVisible="True" Background="Gray" >


            </c:DynamicCanvas>
            <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The controls that are being displayed on DynamicCanvas are of my custom type (below only the most important part):

```
<ContentControl x:Class="SubiektCommerceSynchro.ViewModel.TableControl"
                c:DynamicCanvas.Left="{Binding X,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                c:DynamicCanvas.Top="{Binding Y,Mode=TwoWay}"
                Width="450"  Height="300"
></ContentControl>
```

Now the problem and the question:

The part here that doesn't work is with attached properties c:DynamicCanvas.Left(Top).
Lets put it in steps:

1) DynamicCanvas expects its immediate children to have c:DynamicCanvas.Left and c:DynamicCanvas.Top defined

2) ItemsPanel when putting TableControls onto the DynamicCanvas wraps them in some kind of container

3) DynamicCanvas sees no attached properties on its immediate children => treats them as being positioned at (0,0) and renders them effectively unmoveable.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="c:DynamicCanvas.Left"
                        Value="{Binding X,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="c:DynamicCanvas.Top" 
                        Value="{Binding Y,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I haven't seen your answer. I've found this myself and even wrote a comment about it below. Nevertheless, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the `ControlTemplate` of the item wrapper in the `ItemContainerStyle`. If you set it to simple `ContentPresenter`, the items will not be wrapped in anything (the contents of the `DataTemplate` will be pasted directly into the `DynamicCanvas`).

See [this article](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/).

Comment: The solution was quite different, but the direction was right, so thank you. I had to put `<Setter Property="c:DynamicCanvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                            <Setter Property="c:DynamicCanvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />`
in the ItemContainerStyle.